# Test coverage isn't working as expected in React app

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing

I wrote a react app for weather dashboard...
Code:
**Navbar:**

```
import React from 'react'
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar'
import Toolbar from '@material-ui/core/Toolbar'
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography'

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    title: {    
      flexGrow: 1,
    },
}));

const NavBar = () => {
    const classes = useStyles();
    return(
        <div>
            <AppBar position="fixed">
                <Toolbar>
                    <Typography variant="h6" className={classes.title}>
                        Weather Dashboard
                    </Typography>
                </Toolbar>
            </AppBar>
        </div>
    )
}
export default NavBar;
```

**Dashboard:**

```
import React from 'react';

import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import Card from '@material-ui/core/Card';
import CardContent from '@material-ui/core/CardContent';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography'

import MUIDataTable from "mui-datatables";

// Chart
import Chart from "react-google-charts";

// async
import { useAsync } from 'react-async';

const API_KEY = process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY;
const API_URL = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=bengaluru&appid=${API_KEY}`;

const loadUsers = async () =>
  // That is weather API which pulls Bangalore's 5 day weather data.
  await fetch(API_URL)
    .then(res => (res.ok ? res : Promise.reject(res)))
    .then(res => res.json())
  
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    root: {
        flexGrow: 1,
        padding: theme.spacing(2)
    },
    gridPos: {
        display: 'flex',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        flexGrow: 1,
        padding: theme.spacing(5),
    }  
}));

export default function Dashboard() {
   
    const { data, error, isLoading } = useAsync(
        { 
            promiseFn: loadUsers 
        }
    )
    const classes = useStyles();
    if (isLoading) return "Loading..."
    if (error) return `Something went wrong: ${error.message}`
    // console.log("Data is", data)
    // Pulling temparature data
    const mapped = data.list.map(d => [d.main.temp_min, d.main.temp_max]);
    const chartData = [["Time", "Temperature"], ...mapped];
    // Pulling humidity data
    const map = data.list.map(dt => [dt.main.humidity]);
    const pulledData = [["Humidity"], ...map];
    // Pulling weather and wind data
    const mp = data.list.map(dat => [dat.weather.main, dat.wind.speed, dat.wind.deg, dat.clouds.all]);
    const pulledcomboData = [["Status", "Speed", "Degree", "Clouds"], ...mp];
    // Pulling overall details
    const columns = ["Date and Time", "Wind Speed", "Ground Level Pressure", "Sea Level Pressure", "Humidity", "Temparature"];
    const tableData = data.list.map(tabled => [tabled.dt_txt, tabled.wind.speed, tabled.main.grnd_level, tabled.main.sea_level, tabled.main.humidity, tabled.main.temp]); 
    // console.log("Table data is", tableData);
    const options = {
        filterType: 'checkbox',
    };
        
    if (data)
 
    return (
        <div className="container">
            <div className={classes.root}>
                <div className="App">
                    <h2>Weather Details</h2>
                </div>
                <Grid container spacing={3}>
                    <Grid item xs={6}>
                        <Card className={classes.root}>
                            <CardContent>
                                <Typography className={classes.title} gutterBottom>
                                    Temparature Data:
                                </Typography>
                                <Typography variant="body2" component={'span'}>
                                <Chart
                                    chartType="BarChart"
                                    data={chartData}
                                    loader={<div>Loading Chart</div>}
                                    options={{
                                        chartArea: { 
                                            width: '50%',
                                            height: '50%'
                                        },
                                        hAxis: {
                                          title: 'Maximum Temparature',
                                        },
                                        vAxis: {
                                          title: 'Minimum Temprature',
                                        },
                                    }}
                                />
                                </Typography>
                            </CardContent>
                        </Card>
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item xs={6}>
                        <Card className={classes.root}>
                            <CardContent>
                                <Typography className={classes.title} gutterBottom>
                                    Humidity Histogram:
                                </Typography>
                                <Typography variant="body2" component={'span'}>
                                    <Chart
                                        chartType="Histogram"
                                        data={pulledData}
                                        loader={<div>Loading Chart</div>}
                                        options={{
                                            seriesType: 'bars',
                                            series: { 5: { type: 'line' } },
                                        }}
                                    />
                                </Typography>
                            </CardContent>
                        </Card>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
                <Grid container spacing={3}>
                    <Grid item xs={12}>
                        <Card className={classes.root}>
                            <CardContent>
                                <Typography className={classes.title} gutterBottom>
                                    Wind Data History:
                                </Typography>
                                <Typography variant="body2" component={'span'}>
                                    <Chart
                                        chartType="BubbleChart"
                                        loader={<div>Loading Chart</div>}
                                        data={pulledcomboData}
                                        options={{
                                            chartArea: { 
                                                width: '50%',
                                                height: '50%'
                                            },
                                            bubble: { textStyle: { fontSize: 11 } },
                                        }}
                                    />
                                </Typography>
                            </CardContent>
                        </Card>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
                <Grid container spacing={3}>
                    <Grid item xs={12}>
                        <MUIDataTable
                            title={"Overall data"}
                            data={tableData}
                            columns={columns}
                            options={options}
                        />
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </div>
        </div>
    )

}
```

Then I added tests as given below by following this [link](https://www.telerik.com/blogs/forcing-myself-to-write-unit-tests):
**APILoader.test.js:**

```
const frisby = require('frisby');

const API_KEY = process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY;
const API_URL = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=bengaluru&appid=${API_KEY}`;

it ('should return a status of 200', function () {
  return frisby
    .get(API_URL)
    .expect('status', 200);
});
```

**chartDataLoader.test.js:**

```
const frisby = require('frisby');
const Joi = frisby.Joi; // Frisby exports Joi for convenience on type assersions

const API_KEY = process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY;
const API_URL = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=bengaluru&appid=${API_KEY}`;

it('should return JSON data', async () => {
    return frisby
      .get(API_URL)
      .expect('status', 200)
      .expect('jsonTypes', Joi.object({
            cnt: Joi.number().required(),
            cod: Joi.string().required(),
            message: Joi.number().required()
        }).required()
    );
});
```

**componentLoader.test.js:**

```
    import React from 'react';
    import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
    
    import NavBar from '../navbar';
    import Dashboard from '../dashboard';
    
    test('renders navbar', () => {
  const { getByText }  = render(<NavBar />);
  const linkedElement = getByText(/Weather/);
  expect(linkedElement).toBeInTheDocument();
});

    
    test('renders Dashboard', () => {
      const { getByText } = render(<Dashboard />);
      const linkElement = getByText(/Loading/);
      expect(linkElement).toBeInTheDocument();
    });
```

All tests pass successfully with no warnings/errors. However when I try to check the test coverage by using `yarn test -- --coverage` command, coverage table shows 0.
[image: test]
How can I make test suite cover all the code which is inside `src/components`?

Comment: have you tried this command `yarn test --coverage  --watchAll` ?

Comment: How are you configuring jest? Are you setting  "collectCoverageFrom": [ "src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"]

Comment: @AjayKulkarni could you please share your jest setup? Did you check: `yarn test --coverage  --watchAll=false` works?

Comment: This is my `jest` set up... `"jest": {
    "coverageReporters": [
      "text",
      "html"
    ],
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "js",
      "jsx",
      "ts",
      "tsx",
      "src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"
    ]
  }`

Comment: I tried @shubhamjha's sugestion, got this... https://ibb.co/BwFPpxf

Comment: now when you got the uncovered lines you might improve the test case, does my comment answer your question?

Comment: Yes, your comment answered my question, I'll work on covering uncovered lines...

Comment: shall I post an answer so that you could give me some reputation points?

Comment: @shubhamjha sure, do post your answer as it solved the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`--watchAll` option in jest Watch files for changes and rerun all tests when something changes, [reference](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/cli#--watchall)

so this command `yarn test --coverage  --watchAll` would show coverage of all files.